# SSH Keys on multiple operating systems

Tags: server, ssh, security

I have a Ubuntu Server 13.04 and I currently use password only SSH login.

After seeing how many attempts were made to maliciously login to SSH I need to switch to key based authentication.

I have used https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys and https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys but they all relate to Linux.

I am still not sure how to set up key only login on my Ubuntu Server or how to generate key pairs on Mac OS X and Windows 8 (using Putty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the [Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys) there you will find what you need. Generating key-pairs in OS X is done the same way you would do on any other linux distro take see [this article](https://drupal.org/node/1070130)

```
$ ssh-keygen
```